# Initializing an object inside the constructor and not in initialization list

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, destructor

I've got the following class holding 3 datatypes:

```
   class CentralBank{
    MaxHeap richestBanks;
    HashTable banks;
    AccountTree accounts;

public:
    CentralBank(int numAccounts, Account* accounts, int numBanks, Bank* bankArr);
    void AddAccount(Account account);
    void RemoveAccount(int accountID);
    void AddBank(Bank bank);
    int GetAccountsNumber(int bankID);
    void GetKRichestBanks(unsigned int K, Bank* banks);
    int GetSumBalance (int low, int high);

};
```

Here's the constructor:

```
CentralBank::CentralBank(int numAccounts, Account* accounts, int numBanks,
        Bank* bankArr): accounts(numAccounts,accounts){
    int** locs = new int*[numBanks];
    richestBanks = MaxHeap(numBanks,bankArr, locs);
    banks = HashTable(numBanks,bankArr,locs);
    delete[] locs;
}
```

My problem is that the destructor for the heap and the hash table is called right after their constructor. If I make both of them into pointers it doesn't happen. 
Why does this happen?
Is there a way for them not to be pointers and not have the destructors called right after initialization? Am I not initializing them correctly?

PS: They aren't in the initialization list because their constructors need the "locs" parameter which needs to be initialized.

Comment: The destructor you see is the temporary.

Comment: "*They aren't in the initialization list because their constructors need the "locs" parameter which needs to be initialized.*" Then fix *that*. That's what's causing you to have to use wonky initialization techniques.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I could, but I'd rather not. Nevertheless, I want to understand why this doesn't work so I won't make the same mistake.

Comment: @Shookie : Your mistake is writing code that uses `new` in the first place. ;-]

Comment: Or, if you can, a C++11 smart pointer or boost smart pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Once you enter the body of a constructor, the rules of C++ guarantee that all base classes of the class and all *members* of the class have been initialized. That's why the initialization list is outside of the constructor's body; because it gets called before your constructor body. If you didn't specify a constructor and parameters in your constructor's initialization list, then it will be default initialized.

So `richestBanks` and `banks` have already been initialized at this point. And you can't initialize an object *twice*.

```
richestBanks = MaxHeap(numBanks,bankArr, locs);
```

What this does is create a *new* `MaxHeap` object temporary, then call the copy assignment operator (or move assignment, where appropriate) to copy the new data into `richestBanks`. After which point, the temporary object must be destroyed. That's the destructor call you're seeing.

The correct solution is to stop doing whatever you need `locs` for and find a better way to construct your data, so that you can properly use the initialization list.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!
So is there no way for me to "reinitialize" them?
Either way, I'll probably do as you suggested and remove the whole thing with the locs

Comment: @Shookie if you declare them as shared_ptrs instead and create them inside your constructor on them then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
richestBanks = MaxHeap(numBanks,bankArr, locs)
```

As I remember, this means, that you create a temporary object, run copy constructor to copy it to the richestBanks variable, and then destruct this temp var.

The better solution is to have a reference to the object (MaxHeap&) instead the object itself, or a pointer.

Comment: Almost, it's the copy assignment operator, not the copy constructor.

Comment: even you put them in initialization list the destructor might be called.

Answer (score 0):

*My problem is that the destructor for the heap and the hash table is called right after their constructor.*

The destructors are being called for the temporary instances of MaxHeap and HashTable constructed in the body of the CentralBank constructor, which go out of scope at the end.  These temporaries are *copied* into the member variables `richestBanks` and `banks`, which were *already initialized* on entry into the body of this constructor.

Assuming you really need the array of int pointers, you can set up an auxiliary class to deal with its lifetime according to normal RAII guidelines.  Something like this:

```
class IntPointerArray
{
public:
    IntPointerArray( int num )
    : array_(new int*[num])
    {}
    ~IntPointerArray()
    { delete [] array_; }
    operator int** ()
    { return array_; }
private:
    int** array_;
};
```

Now, extending your class to hold an instance of this as a member:

```
   class CentralBank{
    IntPointerArray locs;
    MaxHeap richestBanks;
    HashTable banks;
    AccountTree accounts;
    // rest omitted
```

And observing the rule that members are initialized in the order of their declarations, your constructor can now look like this:

```
CentralBank::CentralBank(int numAccounts, Account* accounts, int numBanks, Bank* bankArr)
: locs(numBanks)
, richestBanks(numBanks,bankArr, locs) // exploits operator int**
, banks(numBanks,bankArr, locs) // ditto
, accounts(numAccounts,accounts)
{}
```

This way, all members are initialized directly, and no constructor body with temporaries is needed at all.

Whether you should be using an external array like this is worth looking into also.  I'm guessing you really need the data structure known as a [treap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap).